# Python - How To read IRIS CSV Data (a variable) into a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the sample Python Machine Learning "IRIS" dataset (for starting point of a project). These data are POSTed into a Flask web service. Thus, the key difference between what I'm doing and all the examples I can find is that I'm trying to load a Pandas DataFrame from a variable and not from a file or URL which both seem to be easy.

I extract the IRIS data from the Flask's POST request.values. All good. But at that point, I can't figure out how to get the pandas dataframe like the "pd.read_csv(....)" does. So far, it seems the only solution is to parse each row and build up several series I can use with the DataFrame constructor?  There must be something I'm missing since reading this data from a URL is a simple one-liner.

I'm assuming reading a variable into a Pandas DataFrame should not be difficult since it seems like an obvious use-case.

I tried wrapping with io.StringIO(csv_data), then following up with read_csv on that variable, but that doesn't work either.

Note: I also tried things like ...

data = pd.DataFrame(csv_data, columns=['....'])

but got nothing but errors (for example, "constructor not called correctly!")

I am hoping for a simple method to call that can infer the columns and names and create the DataFrame for me, from a variable, without me needing to know a lot about Pandas (just to read and load a simple CSV data set, anyway).

Comment: Try printing csv_data and perhaps editing your post so we can get a better idea of what the problem is.

Comment: Why not ask user to post the iris data CSV file.

Comment: The IRIS data is just for getting things set up. In the real application, the data would be POSTed to a Flask web service from a database so being able to create a DF from CSV data variable (as we're trying to do now) is key. Thanks.